# How to know what changed React State

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I'm trying to fix an issue in my React code, where a reference inside the state is changing on its own. I have added logs on every point where I call `setState` on that reference. However, none of the points are called. I want to know what else might be causing that state to change. What is a possible way of doing this?

Comment: You should post a code sample to better answer the question. The state object in React should never be mutated, but a common source of bugs is mutating the state object without calling setState. Check if you are mutating the state object indirectly without calling setState, or you are mutating some of its nested properties which are stored by reference.

Comment: You'd probably better set a breakpoint at the `setState` call in your debugger, and when reached take a look at the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentDidUpdate`.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (prevState.pokemons !== this.state.pokemons) {
        console.log('pokemons state has changed.')
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, however, I'm trying to find, who changed this.state.pokemons

Comment: You can check for the `setState({pokemons})` in your entire codebase. I dont think we do have any other options